# How to toggle comments of a post with a link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook-comments

I would like to use a simple link, like Facebook does, to toggle (unlike Facebook show AND hide) the comments of a post. However, being the list of posts in my application obtained by iteration, every post apparently can:

1. have comments enclosed in a `div` that share with the comments of all the other posts the same `id` or `class`
2. have comments enclosed in a `div` element with unique `id` or `class` generated using (for instance) the `id` of the post

In the first case, I cannot use the link and its `id` or `class` to toggle with jQuery only the comments belonging to one post: I would toggle the comments of all the posts. There might be a solution though: forget about the link and use the `div` parent to the `div` containing the comments to toggle it:

```
<div id="comments-parent">
  <%= link_to "Show/hide comments", "#", id="comments-link" %>
  <ol id="comments">
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <li id="<% comment.id %>">
        <span class="comment-content"><%= comment.content %></span>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

With jQuery I can do something like this:

```
$('#comments').hide();

$('#comments-parent').click(function() {
    $(this).children('#comments').toggle();
});
```

This solution is horrible... Comments are toggled clicking on a very large area. 
The second case, with a `<ol id="comments-<%=post.id %>">`, could be the solution:

```
$('#comments-all').hide();

$('#comment-link').click(function() {
    $('#comments-1').toggle();
});
```

However I would not know how to realize it, or if it is possible to realize it, that is how to pass to jQuery the information about "all `ids` starting with `comments-`" or above all about a particular `id`.

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to what I would have done. You can however bind it to the link like so:

```
$('.toggleLink').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.post').find('.comments').toggle();
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jwsho1pn/3/) is an example of what I think you want to do.

The reason why this works is due to using `this` which is a context based variable in javascript. In this particular case, `this` refers to the link element that triggered the click event. So from there we can access the correct surrounding elements for `toggle`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I knew jQuery was the solution, but being not that good at it I was stuck. Thanks!